# Extjs autoscroll on panel databinded with a grid

Tags: grid, extjs4, scrollbar, panel

I'm implementing something a lot like the example here: 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid/binding-with-classes.html

I want to put an autoscroll on my details panel but the usual autoScroll: 'true' isn't working. I think this is because the data that would require a scrollbar is being loaded after the panel renders. Does that make sense? Does anyone have any idea on how to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out. Just had to add this to the initComponent: function

```
        this.bodyStyle = {
            background: '#ffffff',
            overflow: 'auto'
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scroll: true,
viewConfig: {
    style: {
        overflow: 'auto',
        overflowX: 'hidden'
    }
}
```

Try the above one.